# How to handle Append Only text fields in a Sharepoint DataSheet view?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

We've created a Sharepoint site to track a process.  Eventually we're going to make a workflow out of it, but in the meantime there's a list we all have to look at which lists the various dates each piece is supposed to be finished.

So basically My group needs to see and update columns X, Y, Z and Comments while ignoring the other 30 billion or so columns.  Which is great in datasheet view because we can easily view our columns, and update them right there without drilling into the item and browsing through all the other crap we don't need.

The problem is the Comments field, in which we really need to see the last actual comment made.  Unfortunately whenever anyone saves the record the field is updated with a blank value (unless they entered a comment) and the last actual comment is lost unless you drill into the item.

Is there some way to get the Datasheet view to show all the entries?

I should also note that I know very little about Sharepoint 2007... so detailed answers would be nice!

Answer (score 1):

Append-only comments are implemented with the version mechanism, so in the Datasheet View you're seeing every row update as a new version of the item with a new comment. In normal data views this logic is handled by the [AppendOnlyHistory control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.appendonlyhistory.aspx). I don't know of any way around this behavior for views that aren't history-aware like the Datasheet.